# Sort outer multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to sort a dataframe highest to lowest based on column B. I can't find an answer on how to sort the outer (i.e. first) index column.

I have this example data:

```
                  A         B
Item    Type
0       X         'rtr'     2
        Tier      'sfg'     104
1       X         'zad'     7
        Tier      'asd'     132
2       X         'frs'     4
        Tier      'plg'     140
3       X         'gfq'     9
        Tier      'bcd'     100
```

Each multi-index row contains a "Tier" row. I want to sort the outer index "Item" based on the "B" column value relating to each "Tier". The "A" column can be ignored for sorting purposes but needs to be included in the dataframe.

```
                  A         B
Item    Type
2       X         'frs'     4
        Tier      'plg'     140
1       X         'zad'     7
        Tier      'asd'     132
0       X         'rtr'     2
        Tier      'sfg'     104
3       X         'gfq'     9
        Tier      'bcd'     100
```

Comment: use `.sort_values('A')`  before the `.groupby()`. It will sort as well

Comment: can you share your raw data so we can try to address the sorting issue.

Comment: Sure, here's the raw data as CSV: https://pastebin.com/raw/8nJnURk7


"Total" column represents "B" in this question. "Item" and "Type" indexes and "Tier" row are the same name


To be clear, in this case Items 2, 4, 7 should be at the top (because Tier's Total values are 23) and Items 0, 1, 3, 5, 6 should be at the bottom (because the Tier's Total values are 22)

Comment: So you want to sort by Item, then by 'B' then by 'Type'. Correct? If so, wouldn't `0` be the first item on the list? Alternatively, if you want to sort by B, then Item, then Type wouldn't 2 within 'B' be the first item so the dataframe will be sorted by Item as 0, then 2, then 1, then 7

Comment: No, it should be 2, 1, 0, 3. The full/outer index row (Item) should move higher or lower depending on its value in the B column for the Tier row only. The reason I worded the question like that was because I saw a previous question that asks to move only the inner index's rows (while keeping the first/outer index's order the same)

Comment: If i understand correctly, in the below result, you want it to be sorted by 2 (total for Tier is 22 and is the smallest of all the items), then by 4, and so on until the smallest items for the first element is sorted, then go to next lowest number for the first element, and so on? In other words, sort by the 22, then by 23. For each 22, sort it by Index, then go to the next highest number and then by next?

Comment: I added a comment by your post. Here's a screenshot to help make it clearer what I want the output to be: https://snipboard.io/eCK5B8.jpg

Comment: I need to figure this out. There may be an easier way. Will look into this tonight.

Comment: I created a sorted list based on my understanding of your problem statement. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That's great thanks! I just changed `tier = tier.sort_values('Total')` to `tier = tier.sort_values('Total', ascending=False)` to make it highest to lowest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Response #2**

Based on all the inputs received, here's the solution. Hope this works for you.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("xyz.txt")

df1 = df.copy()
#capture the original index of each row. This will be used for sorting later
df1['idx'] = df1.index

#create a dataframe with only items that match 'Tier'
#assumption is each Index has a row with 'Tier'
tier = df1.loc[df1['Type']=='Tier']

#sort Total for only the Tier rows
tier = tier.sort_values('Total')

#Create a list of the indexes in sorted order
#this will be the order to print the rows
tier_list = tier['Index'].tolist()

# Create the dictionary that defines the order for sorting
sorterIndex = dict(zip(tier_list, range(len(tier_list))))

# Generate a rank column that will be used to sort the dataframe numerically
df1['Tier_Rank'] = df1['Index'].map(sorterIndex)

#Now sort the dataframe based on rank column and original index
df1.sort_values(['Tier_Rank','idx'],ascending = [True, True],inplace = True)

#drop the temporary column we created
df1.drop(['Tier_Rank','idx'], 1, inplace = True)

#print the dataframe
print (df1)
```

Based on the source data, here's the final output. Let me know if this is in line with what you were looking for.

```
    Index         Type                     Id  ...  Intellect  Strength  Total
12      2  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
13      2    Gauntlets  "6917529202229927889"  ...         16        14     60
14      2       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
15      2    Leg Armor  "6917529202802011569"  ...         15         2     61
16      2          Set                    NaN  ...         58        33    249
17      2         Tier                    NaN  ...          5         3     22
24      4  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
25      4    Gauntlets  "6917529202802009244"  ...          7         9     63
26      4       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
27      4    Leg Armor  "6917529202802011569"  ...         15         2     61
28      4          Set                    NaN  ...         49        28    252
29      4         Tier                    NaN  ...          4         2     22
42      7  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
43      7    Gauntlets  "6917529202791088503"  ...          7        14     61
44      7       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
45      7    Leg Armor  "6917529202229923870"  ...          7        19     57
46      7          Set                    NaN  ...         41        50    246
47      7         Tier                    NaN  ...          4         5     22
0       0  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
1       0    Gauntlets  "6917529202778947311"  ...         10        15     62
2       0       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
3       0    Leg Armor  "6917529202802011569"  ...         15         2     61
4       0          Set                    NaN  ...         52        34    251
5       0         Tier                    NaN  ...          5         3     23
6       1  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
7       1    Gauntlets  "6917529202778947311"  ...         10        15     62
8       1       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
9       1    Leg Armor  "6917529202229923870"  ...          7        19     57
10      1          Set                    NaN  ...         44        51    247
11      1         Tier                    NaN  ...          4         5     23
18      3  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
19      3    Gauntlets  "6917529202229927889"  ...         16        14     60
20      3       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
21      3    Leg Armor  "6917529202229923870"  ...          7        19     57
22      3          Set                    NaN  ...         50        50    245
23      3         Tier                    NaN  ...          5         5     23
30      5  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
31      5    Gauntlets  "6917529202802009244"  ...          7         9     63
32      5       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
33      5    Leg Armor  "6917529202229923870"  ...          7        19     57
34      5          Set                    NaN  ...         41        45    248
35      5         Tier                    NaN  ...          4         4     23
36      6  Chest Armor  "6917529202229928161"  ...         17         8     62
37      6    Gauntlets  "6917529202791088503"  ...          7        14     61
38      6       Helmet  "6917529202223945870"  ...         10         9     66
39      6    Leg Armor  "6917529202802011569"  ...         15         2     61
40      6          Set                    NaN  ...         49        33    250
41      6         Tier                    NaN  ...          4         3     23

[48 rows x 11 columns]
```

**New Response:**

Based on the [source data file](http://pastebin.com/raw/8nJnURk7) shared, here's the group by and sort. Let me know how you want the values to be sorted. I have assumed that you want it sorted by Index, then Total.

```
df = df.groupby(['Index','Type',])\
       .agg({'Total':'mean'})\
       .sort_values(['Index','Total'])
```

The output of this will be as follows:

```
                   Total
Index Type              
0     Tier            23
      Leg Armor       61
      Chest Armor     62
      Gauntlets       62
      Helmet          66
      Set            251
1     Tier            23
      Leg Armor       57
      Chest Armor     62
      Gauntlets       62
      Helmet          66
      Set            247
2     Tier            22
      Gauntlets       60
      Leg Armor       61
      Chest Armor     62
      Helmet          66
      Set            249
3     Tier            23
      Leg Armor       57
      Gauntlets       60
      Chest Armor     62
      Helmet          66
      Set            245
4     Tier            22
      Leg Armor       61
      Chest Armor     62
      Gauntlets       63
      Helmet          66
      Set            252
```

**Initial Response:**

I dont have your raw data. Created some data to show you how sorting would work on groupby data. See if this is what you are looking for.

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Type':['Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive'],
                   'Air': ['Good','Bad', 'Bad', 'Good'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

df = df.groupby(['Animal','Type','Air'])\
       .agg({'Max Speed':'mean'})\
       .sort_values('Max Speed')
print(df)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
                     Max Speed
Animal Type    Air            
Parrot Wild    Bad        24.0
       Captive Good       26.0
Falcon Captive Bad       370.0
       Wild    Good      380.0
```

Without the sort command, the output will be a bit different.

```
df = df.groupby(['Animal','Type','Air'])\
       .agg({'Max Speed':'mean'})
```

This will result in below. The Max Speed is not sorted. Instead it is using the group by sort of Animal then Type:

```
                     Max Speed
Animal Type    Air            
Falcon Captive Bad       370.0
       Wild    Good      380.0
Parrot Captive Good       26.0
       Wild    Bad        24.0
```

Comment: The order of rows in "Type" should remain the same as the original. Only Index position should change (depending on the Tier's value in Total column). Also the other "A" column should remain in the dataframe. Thus 0, 1 and 3 should be at the top because they have the highest tier totals (23), while 2 and 4 should be at the bottom (only have tier totals of 22)